# Rest API data stored in locally - Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, sqlite, rest

I have a requirement to store data locally to use within a Flutter mobile application.  This stored data will be used for when the device is offline and will need to be updated, whilst offline.

On initial login of the application, data must be pulled from a **REST API** and stored locally to be displayed within the app.

Does anyone have any pointers as to what is the best method for this?  I've looked at Sqflite but i can't seem to see any tutorials or documentation on setting this up using an API to 'fill' the data initially.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look Flutter docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence. There are examples too.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this.

One option is simply using [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio), which has caching support built in.

Or, you could use something like [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) or [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) along with [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to to persist the data yourself (depending on what level of control you want/need).

You could also encapsulate the data in a state management solution like [riverpod](https://riverpod.dev) (specifically a FutureProvider in this case) which [will soon have offline persistence support](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/1032).

If building an application from scratch, I'd recommend the riverpod route (and it will soon have that offline persistence support).